# MongoDB query on every char, with regex - terrible idea?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an input field where I am trying to simulate a Google-style instant search. So, on every keyup, I send a request to my Node back-end to query Mongo for the `/currentSearchQuery/` (with regex for similar results).

So, if a user types "apple", I'd send 5 GET requests to Node, querying Mongo for...
`/a/`
`/ap/`
`/app/`
`/appl/`
`/apple/`

Is this terribly inefficient/bad/wrong in some way? I'm not indexing my database - should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely index the fields for which you are going to search frequently this will improve the performance and speed of the search result.
Next, it is not a good idea to search for every keyup. Generally, you should wait upto 3 characters to feed in and then hit the search query.

Additional Tip: For the faster search you might want to use `elasticsearch`.